# Swift 3 - Get value from array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift3

Trying to get the value and the key of a dictionary that's stored in an array to populate two UILabels.

My array looks as follows:

```
var fromLocations = [["marco" : "polo"],["jekyll" : "hide"],["freddy" : "jason"]]
```

I'm getting the index by a collection view's indexPath. Currently trying the following:

```
cell.locationName.text = fromLocations[indexPath.item].values[1]
```

I've tried a bunch of other ways but I can't nail it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
var fromLocations = [["marco" : "polo1"],["marco" : "polo2"],["marco" : "polo3"]]
let marco = fromLocations[0]["marco"]
print("marco = \(marco)")
```

This prints "polo1". Basically you are accessing the first item of the array which is a dictionary. You then access that dictionary the way you would normally access a dictionary.

So a break down would be:

```
let fromLocations = [["marco" : "polo"],["marco" : "polo"],["marco" : "polo"]]
let theDictionary = fromLocations[0]
let value = theDictionary["marco"]
```

---

To just get the values as an array with using the key (which is strange), turn the values into an array.

```
var fromLocations = [["marco" : "polo1"],["marco" : "polo2"],["marco" : "polo3"]]
let marco = Array(fromLocations[0].values)[0]
print("marco = \(marco)")
```

This will print "polo1"

Comment: Kind of, I've used placeholder text to show an array of dictionaries - both marco and polo would be different in each set.

Comment: Ah gotcha. If you don't need the dictionary keys for access, why not just use an array of strings?

Comment: Thanks - I was trying to be too clever, I guess an array of strings will be fine :)